# collect all array items from each object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have 2 entities:

```
class A {
    ...
}
class B {
    IEnumerable<B> bs;
}
```

I have array of A's and I need to get all the B's in one IEnumerable. I can do:

```
IEnumerable<A> as=....;

IEnumerable<IEnumerable<B>> bss=as.Select(x=>x.bs);

IEnumerable<B> all=null;
foreach (IEnumerable<B> bs is bss) {
    if (all==null) { all=bs; }
    else { all=all.Contact(bs); }
}
```

I want to know if there is shorter way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because you can't call a variale `as` (it's a reserved keyword) and your `A` class doesn't appear to have a field called `bs` (since you have it on `B`.) Please try to provide *working* samples with your questions.

Comment: @dlev: This is JUST an example to explain my question and not code that should compile. If you get the point - it is enough. Don't get much into details if you understand the question.

Comment: @Naor if your code has errors like dlev mentions it will confuse people who are trying to answer your question. I recommend editing your question to provide a better example and give better names as all the b, bs, bss stuff can be hard on the eyes to follow.

Comment: @Naor I understand that it's just a sample, and the choice of variable (while illegal) doesn't matter *much*. But providing code that compiles, with types and fields used consistently helps get you better answers, and *really* helps others who have a similar problem and stumble across this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Use SelectMany that will concatenate all the IEnumerables together

```
var all = as.SelectMany(a => a.bs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SelectMany` method to flatten a single level of nesting:

```
all = as.SelectMany(a => a.bs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SelectMany`:

```
foreach (var b in allAs.SelectMany(a => a.Bs))
{
    // Do work here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting SelectMany to flatten the B's?

```
IEnumerable<B> allBs = as.SelectMany(a => a.bs);
```

or using LINQ expressions:

```
IEnumerable<B> allBs = from a in as
                       from b in a.bs
                       select b;
```